# ZIO Environment construction

Tags: scala, zio

I started experimenting with ZIO, and was trying to run the following highly sophisticated program:

```
import logger.{Logger, _}
import zio.console._
import zio.{system, _}

object MyApp extends App {

  override def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[ZEnv, Nothing, Int] = {

    app
      .provideSome[Logger](_ => Slf4jLogger.create) //1 
      .fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)
  }

  val app: ZIO[Console with system.System with Logger, SecurityException, Unit] =
    for {
      _         <- info("This message from the logger") //2
      maybeUser <- system.env("USER")
      _         <- maybeUser match {
                      case Some(userName) => putStrLn(s"Hello ${userName}!")
                      case None => putStrLn("I don't know your name")
                    }
    } yield ()
}
```

(Slf4jLogger is https://github.com/NeQuissimus/zio-slf4j)

If I comment lines `//1` and `//2` out everything works fine. But in the above form I get a type mismatch error:

```
Error:(13, 45) type mismatch;
 found   : logger.Slf4jLogger
 required: zio.console.Console with zio.system.System with logger.Logger
      .provideSome[Logger](_ => Slf4jLogger.create)
```

I don't understand the following:

1. The program required a `Console` and a `System` instance in the environment, yet I did not have to `.provide` it before, when I was not logging. Why? And why do I suddenly need it?
2. According to the scaladoc, `.provideSome` *Provides *some* of the environment required to run this effect, leaving the remainder R0.* For me that means that I don't have to provide the full environment type, I could add the required modules one by one - yet it seems to expect the full ZEnv type, just like `.provide` - so what's the point?
3. I cannot instantiate an anonymous class by `new Logger with Console.Live with system.System.Live`, because the Slf4jLogger has a factory method in the companion object. How can I use this factory method with the other traits?
4. Since creating a logger instance in Java is kind of effectful, is `.provide` even the right function to call?

PS: I was able to get this working in a kind of ugly way:

```
    app
      .provideSome[ZEnv](_ =>
        new Console with Logger with system.System {
          override val console = Console.Live.console
          override val system = System.Live.system
          override val logger = Slf4jLogger.create.logger
        }
      ) //1
      .fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)
```

This compiles and runs, but overriding the mixed in traits' inner members does not seem right...

And it works in exactly the same way with `.provide`:

```
    app
      .provide(
        new Console with Logger with system.System {
          override val console = Console.Live.console
          override val system = System.Live.system
          override val logger = Slf4jLogger.create.logger
        }
      ) //1
      .fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)
```

What is going on?

Comment: If I comment out lines `//1` and `//2` in the original code I still have compile error `Error:(11, 12) type mismatch;
 found   : zio.ZIO[zio.console.Console with zio.system.System with nequi.zio.logger.Logger,Nothing,Int]
 required: zio.ZIO[zio.ZEnv,Nothing,Int]
    (which expands to)  zio.ZIO[zio.clock.Clock with zio.console.Console with zio.system.System with zio.random.Random with zio.blocking.Blocking,Nothing,Int]
      .fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid you do have to return an instance that implements all the traits you want to provide.

If you look at the example in ZIO's documentation for `provideSome`, you see that they are doing the exact same thing: They are taking a `Console` and turn it into a `Console with Logging`.

```
/**
   * Provides some of the environment required to run this effect,
   * leaving the remainder `R0`.
   *
   * {{{
   * val effect: ZIO[Console with Logging, Nothing, Unit] = ???
   *
   * effect.provideSome[Console](console =>
   *   new Console with Logging {
   *     val console = console
   *     val logging = new Logging {
   *       def log(line: String) = console.putStrLn(line)
   *     }
   *   }
   * )
   * }}}
   */
```

> For me that means that I don't have to provide the full environment type, I could add the required modules one by one

No. You have to provide an instance of the full environment type to the effect you are wrapping (because it needs that). I think this is because we want to have this checked at compile-time and there is no way (without macros) to generate a "mash-up" stacked environment without spelling out how to do that. There will probably be some macros for that down the road.

> just like .provide - so what's the point?

The difference is that with `.provide` you have to make up that instance of the required environment from scratch without any input. So that as a result, the effect (with your wrapping) no longer requires anything.

Whereas with `.provideSome` you yourself can request an environment to help you construct the instance you are providing. That environment will be passed into your function. In the example above, they require a `Console` and augment it to `Console with Logging` (by using the `console` instance they are given). As a result, `effect.provideSome[Console](...)` still requires a `Console` (whereas written with `.provide` it would require `Nothing`).

```
.provideSome[ZEnv](_ =>
        new Console with Logger with system.System {
          override val console = Console.Live.console
```

Since you are using `provideSome[ZEnv]`, you should probably not access the global singletons `Console.Live`, but take that from the `env` being passed in:

```
.provideSome[ZEnv](env =>
        new Console with Logger with system.System {
          override val console = env.console
```

> The program required a Console and a System instance in the environment, yet I did not have to `.provide` it before

That is because `ZEnv`, the default environment already provides these two.

> Since creating a logger instance in Java is kind of effectful, is .provide even the right function to call?

Personally, I would ignore that constructing loggers is effectful. It does not seem like something worth tracking. I consider it some basic facility that it is almost a part of class-loading.

If you did want to track the effect, you could do

```
app
  .provideSomeM(env => for {
     logger <- UIO(Slf4jLogger.create)
   } yield new MyEnvironment(env, logger)
  )
```

Comment: For macros to help with the boilerplate, look at https://github.com/zio/zio-macros/blob/master/docs/mix.md

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain.

If you have a look at what `ZEnv` is it's an alias for `Clock with Console with System with Random with Blocking`. So, when you started implementing `def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[ZEnv, Nothing, Int]` zio already provided you with these capabilities.

Your `app` variable signature has a return type of zio with environment `Console with System with Logger` - one thing that stands out is a `Logger` capability. It's not standard so ZIO can't provide it for you. You have to provide it yourself.

That's what you did using `.provideSome[Logger]` - you eliminated one of the capabilities from environment requirements making it type compatible with the standard:

```
type ZEnv = Clock with Console with System with Random with Blocking
type YourEnv = Console with System
type Proof = ZEnv <:< YourEnv
```

Comment: My logic was also along these lines. However the first code _does not compile_. So this logic is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that I use:

```
import logger.{Logger, _}
import zio.console._
import zio.{system, _}

object MyApp extends App {

  override def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[ZEnv, Nothing, Int] = {

    app
      .fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)
  }

  val app: ZIO[Environment, SecurityException, Unit] =
    for {
      _         <- info("This message from the logger").provide( Slf4jLogger.create) // 1
      maybeUser <- system.env("USER")
      _         <- maybeUser match {
                      case Some(userName) => putStrLn(s"Hello ${userName}!")
                      case None => putStrLn("I don't know your name")
                    }
    } yield ()
}
```

1. I provide it directly in the `for-comprehension` of the app. All the rest you have from the `zio.App`.